# Bubbling after storing chili fried in oil and vinegar over night

Tags: food-safety

To make spicy oil, I followed this procedure:

- first I fine-minced dried chili
- I put them in a pan with wine vinegar (7% acidity), some salt and oil and cooked it until it started to go brown (which I assumed is the point at which all water evaporated and temperatures went higher than 100°).
- then I put everything in a small jar. The jar was not cleaned by boiled, but it was cleaned by washing machine some time ago.
- I closed the jar and left it at room temperature overnight.

This morning I found bubbles:
[image]

Should I be worried?

I was suggested to fry it again, but I'm afraid it will burn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a food preservation recipe develops unusual behavior, you have to consider the product unsafe, even if the recipe itself was safe. The bubbles are a clear sign of fermentation, and your chili is now unsafe.

> I was suggested to fry it again

Once a food is unsafe, there are no ways to turn it back into being safe. Even if you fry again, it will still be unsafe.

Comment: even after just one night and after hot oil preparation?

Comment: The "one night" part doesn't matter. First, if your food was not suitable for being stored at room temperature, it became unsafe after two hours at room temperature, and one night is too long. Second, the obvious fermentation cancels all other considerations. The hot oil also doesn't matter, it is just for taste and has nothing to do with preservation.